How to fix incomplete grep
So I constantly make the mistake of mis-typing my grep commands.
I mean to type grep searchstring *  However, I often forget to put the * and end up hitting enter after typing grep searchstring.
This sends my command line into a frozen > that I cannot figure out how to get out of.
No matter what I try to type after that, I cannot escape the > doom.  I have to close my session and restart it, thus losing all my progress.
What is the secret to escaping this problem?
I have tried ctrl + z, ctrl + x, ctrl +d, esc, another *, ', ", ;, literally anything I can think of, I do not know how to fix it after I "mess up" my grep.
What is it expecting when I forget to put where to search, and how can I fix it?

For more clarity:
Normally, when you are working in command line, you get a command prompt.  For example right now my command prompt is bash-5.2$.  So my screen looks like this:
bash-5.2$ pwd
/bin/bash
bash-5.2$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt
bash-5.2$ grep searchstring *
file1.txt:searchstring
file2.txt:searchstring
bash-5-2$

The indication of the bash-5.2$ means the prompt is ready for a new command.  The above grep was typed in correctly, with a *, and therefore it outputted the result and went back to a regular prompt.
Now when I make this grep mistake, this is what it looks like:
bash-5.2$ pwd
/bin/bash
bash-5.2$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt
bash-5.2$ grep searchstring     //here I forgot the *
>

That > is not a normal prompt.  It does not accept commands.  It does nothing but make more of them if I press Enter:
bash-5.2$ pwd
/bin/bash
bash-5.2$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt
bash-5.2$ grep searchstring
>
>
> 

I don't know how to get back to a normal prompt.  I don't know how to escape > land.  I've tried ctrl + all the letters, nothing works.

it is reading stdin and the exit command should be ctrl+d ( https://superuser.com/questions/603670/when-i-grep-no-particular-file-the-terminal-stops-working )

Cannot replicate. Are you sure this happens after grep searchstring? The standard $PS2 is >, maybe this is what you saw. We can see it after grep 'searchstring (Enter) because of the unpaired quote. Normally Ctrl+C should help. Please confirm this happens after grep searchstring for you. If not, [edit] and give a real example. What is your OS? What is your shell? Terminal emulator? grep?

I'm not sure why you can't replicate it.  It's happened to me over the past 10 years, on dozens of different operating systems, in every shell.  You SEEM to be replicating it, like you said, you get the > as well.  ctrl C doesn't work.  None of the cntl + [any letter] works to get out of the > and back to regular prompt.

@ Yorik.  THANK YOU!  I've been trying ctrl + d but I guess I was hitting it too quickly?  I would just hit ctrl + z, then c, then x, then d, all very fast trying to get out of > hell, and it would never work.  I guess I just have to give it a second.  ctrl + d was the answer!

"You SEEM to be replicating it" – No. I got > after "executing" grep 'searchstring and I know why and what happened. I got no prompt after executing grep searchstring and I know why and what happened. You got > after grep searchstring and I cannot replicate this.

About Ctrl+D : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177651/108618

You can answer your own Q to resolve it but I guess technically, this is a dupe

@KamilMaciorowski "I know why and what happened".  It's very nice that you know why and what happened.  I do not know why and what happened.  That is why I am asking!  If you could just share your knowledge, and tell me why this is happening and how to fix it, you would be answering my question.  You replicated the behavior I am seeing perfectly.  You seem to know exactly why it happens.  All you needed to do now was share with me that knowledge that you have as to why it happens, and you would be answering my question.

@Yorik but you are the one who had the answer.  I did not know about cntl + d.  You should write the answer so I can accept it!

Sigh… You wrote I "replicated the behavior", but I'm telling you for the second time that we did not get the same results. Where you get > I get no prompt at all. I notice I get > after "executing" grep 'searchstring which is not what you executed. The single-quote makes the difference. What I've got I can explain, but your experience is yet different and I can neither replicate nor explain it.

This question is similar to: When I grep no particular file the terminal stops working. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Might this be an issue with CTRL-C / V having been assigned to COPY & PASTE ?  Which terminal and Shell is in use here?  Can this be set in e.g. .inputrc ?

A summary of few possible scenarios:
$ grep searchstring "* or $ grep searchstring '*
will expect a closing quote ( " or ' ) before attempting anything.
Here the $PS2 prompt will be shown, the default string for this prompt is >
$ grep searchstring *
looks inside all files in current dir
$ grep searchstring
will expect data from stdin, e.g. some pasted text or a e.g. a list to check in...
$ grep searchstring <<EOF
will expect text pasted (as above) with a single line havig just EOF - to mark the end of the text.

For all these CTRL+D marks the end of pasted text or CTRL-C should stop any further actions.
If that does not work: Note that there MAY be an enabled Shell (e.g. .inputrc?) setting
for having COPY & PASTE on CTRL-C and V.
This will of course inhibit CTRL-C from acting as the "stop-key".
This same setting MIGHT enable the use of the BREAK-key as a replacement.
Try it out by stopping this:
$ while true ; do  echo -n "." ; sleep 1 ; done


Thank you.  Ctrl + c truly does nothing, it does not work.  Ctrl + d does seem to work.

... well, that MAY be an issue with your Shell, or maybe setting COPY & PASTE keys to be CTRL-C / CTRL-V also in the Terminal (Normally/Usually SHIFT+CTRL C/V due to the clash here)

THAT'S IT! THAT'S WHAT IT IS! That's why Ctrl + c doesn't work!  I have it set to "copy".  Omg.  THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Right, more text above to reflect that.
